# Using MD5 engine in POCO libraries to hash binary array

Tags: poco-libraries

New to Poco libraries.

I want to calculate a MD5 value on a binary array.  I first wrote in hex decimal format, then convert to a binary string.  Then I call MD5 engine.  Why my code does not work?

```
 std::istringstream message1 ("0162010d00000000000000000000000000000000000103030303030303030303030301a0c000033131394040767a7733672e636f6d2c06313030300506000056cc2806000000011a0c00003297c806000000001f11300003297cf12303030303030303030303030303030301a0c00003297cb06000000011a0e000028af08083331313237301a0a000028af17040a001a15000028af160f821301845802130184015ae401");


 Poco::HexBinaryDecoder message2 (message1);
 std::string message3;
 message2 >> message3;

 MD5Engine engine;
 engine.update (message3.data(), message1.str().length() / 2);
 cout << "\n digest1: " << DigestEngine::digestToHex(engine.digest());
```

Thanks for help!.
DD

Comment: What do you mean "not work"?  What happens when you run your code?  What error or undesirable behavior do you observe?

Comment: Every time when running, I got a different digest value.  It should be a fixed value.  All examples are for MD5 (ASCII string).  This is a binary string.  No idea if I transfer from hex decimal to binary array correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that `message3` always has the same value?  Especially in C(++) I'd wonder about shifting unallocated values.

Comment: message3 presents different values.  That's why I am confused.

Comment: I think the error come from: message2 >> message3;   How to "flush" the whole message2 to message3?